# Defining Classes in Typescript definition files

Tags: typescript

I feel like what I'm trying to do it pretty simple, but my compiler keeps telling me: "Cannot use new with an expression who's type lacks a call or construct signature."

All I'm trying to do is define a class, rather than an interface, inside of a definition file. An abbreviated version of my code is as follows:

```
declare module jsforce {

    declare class Connection {

        constructor(params: ConnectionParams);

    }
}

declare module "jsforce" {
    var jsforce: jsforce.JSForce;
    export = jsforce;
}
```

The on the page where I'm getting the error:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/jsforce.d.ts" />
import jsforce = require('jsforce');

// Wapper for JSForce
export class JSForce {

  public connection: jsforce.Connection;

  constructor() {

  }

  connect(params: jsforce.ConnectionParams) {
    this.connection = new jsforce.Connection({})
  }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The following compiles just fine with latest typescript:

jsforce.d.ts:

```
declare module jsforce {

    class Connection 
    {
        constructor(params: string);
    }
}

declare module "jsforce" 
{
    export = jsforce;
}
```

app.ts

```
import jsforce = require('jsforce');

// Wapper for JSForce
export class JSForce 
{

    public connection: jsforce.Connection;

    constructor() 
    {

    }

    connect(params: jsforce.Connection) 
    {
        this.connection = new jsforce.Connection('12')
    }
}
```